# How to get files in cache directory in android?

Tags: android, file

In my android app, I make files in a directory I get using this function (notice its putting in a subdirectory).

```
gsFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "test/aa.txt");
```

But how do I iterate through the files in that directory now?

I tried

```
File dir = new File(getCacheDir(), "test/aa.txt");
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {

}
```

but it crashed on File f

Comment: dir is a file its not a directory..its not give you any list files..you can't iterate over it..

Comment: How do I get the directory?

Answer (score 18):

Change your code like this and try..

```
    File dir = new File(getCacheDir(), "test");
    if (dir.exists()) {
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            //perform here your operation
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is getCacheDir() ?

Comment: It's nothing but your project's cache folder

Answer (score 3):

Using the below code you can get all the files which are there in your app's cache directory and you can iterate over it and perform whatever is required

```
File dir = new File(mContext.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        if (dir.exists()) {
            for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
                f.getName();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `mContext.getCacheDir()` returns the absolute path itself, no need to use `getAbsolutePath()` in the chaining call